# How to analyze binarised-time-series with python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I hope you will forgive my poor English.

I want to analyze the binarised time-series data like the following with Python(Pandas).

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> s = pd.Series([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0])
>>> type(s)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>> s
0     False
1     False
2     False
3      True
4      True
5      True
6      True
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11     True
12     True
13    False
dtype: bool
```

And I want to extract the start and stop of the index whose value is True.
I tried the following.

```
>>> diff = s.diff().dropna()
>>> diff
1     False
2     False
3      True
4     False
5     False
6     False
7      True
8     False
9     False
10    False
11     True
12    False
13     True
dtype: object
>>> idxs = diff[diff].index.to_series()
>>> idxs
3      3
7      7
11    11
13    13
dtype: int64
>>> events = pd.concat(
        [idxs[0::2].reset_index(drop=True),
            idxs[1::2].reset_index(drop=True)],
        axis=1)\
        .apply(lambda r: pd.Interval(r[0], r[1]), axis=1)
>>> events
0      (3, 7]
1    (11, 13]
dtype: interval
```

In this way, I successfully extract data.
However, This code seems a little ugly.
I thought there might be better code or a library that does that.

If you know about that, I would appreciate it if you could let me know.
I also don't know whether `type(events) == pd.Series[pd.Interval]` is appropriate, please give me a better idea.
Of course, the actual data to be analyzed is much larger.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative:

```
pd.Series([pd.Interval(x.index[0], x.index[-1]+1)
           for _,x in s[s].groupby((~s).cumsum())])
```

Or, if you don't have a range index:

```
m = s|s.shift()
pd.Series([pd.Interval(x.index[0], x.index[-1])
           for _,x in s[m].groupby((~m).cumsum())])
```

output:

```
0      (3, 7]
1    (11, 13]
dtype: interval
```

used input:

```
s = pd.Series([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]).astype(bool)
```

Comment: have you had a chance to give it a try?